# C# iTextSharp Error while pdf file creation

Tags: c#, pdf

Hello this is my code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "PDF file|*.pdf", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    try
                    {
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(richTextBox1.Text));

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In this code process I got an NullReferenceException error:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
```

on this line, please help me!

Comment: Could you please check which of the both is "null". sfd(.FileName) or doc?

Comment: I guess there is problem with doc

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of that error.

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work. Ensure that your anti-virus software isn't causing the issue.

Comment: Don't use any antivirus software, just windows security! But I try it still got same error! Don't understand why?

Comment: Which version of `iTextSharp` are you using? Did you download/install it using NuGet? Your code does throw an exception if `richTextBox1.Text` is null or empty (`System.IO.IOException`) - but on `doc.Close();`

Comment: I recommend that you split your composite statements into single statements and then either use the debugger to step through your code, or use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`  to assist in your debugging. Of course, you might try creating a new project and see if you get the same result first.